# How do I setup a HOSTS file on different operating systems?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, hosts, multi-platform

Please provide examples of how this can be setup on client and server versions of various operating systems.

Comment: I guess you need to add more information on what you are looking for, since setting up hosts file for any OS (windows or Linux) is pretty much the same, except or the path

Comment: This was something I was looking into at the time and figured it was good content to have on ServerFault.com.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hosts file on Linux/Unix:

```
/etc/hosts

ip.nu.mb.er   name1 name2
```

Hosts file on Windows:

```
%WINDOWS%\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts (e.g. C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts)

ip.nu.mb.er   name1 name2
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you're asking how to find the file (it will most likely exist already):

- In a Unix-like operating system (including Mac OS X and Linux), you'll typically find the `hosts` file in `/etc/hosts`. Note that Mac OS X does not by default show you the `etc` directory. You can show it in various ways, such as by choosing **Go → Go to Folder…** in Finder, and typing `/etc`.
- In an NT-based operating system (including Windows XP and Windows Vista), the `etc` directory is slightly hidden, in `%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\`, e.g. `C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`.